# Centrally align an absolute positioned div with whitespace:nowrap

Tags: css

I am dealing with an image caption in some outputted code that I can't alter but must style using CSS and I am having a hard time making the div with the caption get in the center.

The snippet below shows my predicament.  The midpoint of the sentence should align with the midpoint of the container (In this example it would represent a T shape).

```css
#container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#sentence{
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="sentence">
    This is a sentence that stretched on a bit
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS alone?

I tried this:

```css
#container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#sentence{
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  right:-50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="sentence">
    This is a sentence that stretched on a bit
  </div>
</div>
```

But the sentence div is re-sized to what it would be without the `nowrap`.

Comment: I can't control the size so using a fixed offset won't work unfortunately as if image is re-sized then that offset will not represent the centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with absolute can be a little tricky especially when you don't know the width.

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to center the text on an image.

So, instead of going with

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="sentence">
    This is a sentence that stretched on a bit
  </div>
</div>
```

I use,

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="img-container"></div>
    <div id="sentence">This is a sentence that stretched on a bit</div>
</div>
```

So, now I can position the child elements (atleast for this example)

And my css looks like this.

```
#container{
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
#img-container {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    display: inline-block;
}
#sentence {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    top : 0;
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/wvx6fggh/)

Comment: Thanks!  I don't have to use absolute positioning it's just the way I approached it.  The code is actually laid out like in your example so I am having a play with it.  It doesn't work when the caption is smaller than the image though so I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I think I might have to make a new question with code closer to what I'm actually dealing with.  The issue comes when 100% of sentence is actually smaller then the text inside it.  I am trying to get around that without cutting the overflow off with the "..." although I've been at it a while and it feels impossible.

Comment: I decided its best to just use your answer.  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the body (or outer container element), you can set `text-align:center` on `#sentence`, and then give it a negative left margin = body/2 - #container/2:

```css
#container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#sentence{
  width:500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  text-align:center;
  left: -225px;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="sentence">
    This is a sentence that stretched on a bit
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't as it can change in size.  This is my dilemma.  The container size and caption size may vary.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Back to it then...  Sorry about that.